# Button to switch languages in Streamlit?

Tags: python, streamlit

In my Streamlit app, I store the name of the current language in session state. All the translated text is in a dictionary and I am looking at the session state language value to display the current one.

The problem is, I have some multiselect and select box items that do not seem to get translated, even when I update the language value in session state. How do I refresh them while keeping the other information in session state?

```
def main():
    st.session_state.lang = 'en'
    min_max_date = util_funcs.min_max_date(st.session_state['df'])

    # More code here

    # The "translate" button
    with st.sidebar:
        st.button(label='EN', on_click=lambda: st.session_state.update({'lang': 'en'}))

    with st.form(key='map_properties'):
        # This is the label I want to reload
        st.multiselect(
            content['ams_selector'][st.session_state.lang],
            options=stations,
            default=stations,
            key='station_selector'
        )

        st.selectbox(
            content['metric_selector'][st.session_state.lang],
            options=metrics,
            key='metric_selector'
        )

        submit_button = st.form_submit_button(
            content['submit_button'][st.session_state.lang],
            on_click=form_callback
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not reproduce your code specifically, because there are some elements that are missing. However, my example below attempts to achieve what I think you are trying to do.

In my example:

- I store the stations in a dictionary
- I made up the callback function for demonstration purposes only
- I included two language options (EN and SP)
- The multi-select box in the form will change depending on which language is selected.
- The default language is EN.
- Note that the EN and SP button are both `false` at the beginning.
- I display the session_state at the bottom of the page for debugging and demonstration purposes.

Here is the code:

```py
import streamlit as st

# The station labels in language 'en' and 'sp'
stations = {"en": ['en_A', 'en_B'], 
            "sp":['sp_A', 'sp_B']}

# Function for the form submit button - to show what was selected
def form_callback():
    st.title("Form submitted")
    st.write(st.session_state.station_selector)

# Buttons on the sidebar for language selection
with st.sidebar:
        st.header("Select language:")
        st.button(label='EN', key='en')
        st.button(label='SP', key='sp')

# The form changes depending on the language
with st.form(key='map_properties'):
    if st.session_state.sp:
        station_choice = stations["sp"]
    else:
        station_choice = stations["en"]
    
    st.multiselect(
        label = 'ams_selector',
        options=station_choice,
        default=station_choice,
        key='station_selector'
    )
        
    submit_button = st.form_submit_button(label="Submit", on_click=form_callback)
    
# Display the session state for debugging purposes        
st.header("Session State Variables:")
st.write(st.session_state)
```

**This is what the page looks like when the `EN` button is selected:**

[image: EN selected]

**This is what the page looks like when the `SP` button is selected:**

[image: SP selected]